# bcrypt and sanitizing password?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, sanitize

I want to allow using special chars in password, however I would like to know: is it safe to use untouched password from `$_POST` and then store its hash in the database?

Like This:

```
password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

and

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashFromDatabase)
```

Username would be validated for alphanumeric, and both stored in database via PDO?

Comment: All hashing functions are binary-safe.

Comment: I assumed that it was okay, but I could not find anywhere if there is a security problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Although you will not have any problems with the special characters, you can with the length. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

> Caution
>
> Using the PASSWORD_BCRYPT for the algo parameter, will result in the
>   password parameter being truncated to a maximum length of 72
>   characters.

Now the truncated passwords will always match, but you might give users a false sense of security as passwords longer than 72 characters are truncated.

See a [simple example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j0WznF).

A bit of a hypothetical situation though...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe to use the `$_POST['password']` variable directly as input of the `password_hash()` function, because BCrypt even works with binary input. The output of the function is a hash string, which cannot contain any "harmful" characters regarding SQL-injection.